# Standard UITableView section footer view with hyperlinks

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am trying to implement a `UITableView` section footer view with hyperlinks. I want it to look like all the other standard grouped `UITableView` section footer views, with the same metrics, font, colors, etc., just with clickable hyperlinks. As much as possible, I would like to avoid hard-coding any layout values, including height. Ideally, I would like to avoid external dependencies such as `TTAttributedLabel`.

Edit: The hyperlinks are to be underlined text links, not underlined URLs, so data detectors don't apply.

Answer (score 5):

I thought this would be easy, but it seems that I was wrong.

#### Getting the standard fonts and colors:

- If I instantiate my own UITableViewHeaderFooterView instance, the `textLabel` font (on iOS 9) does not match UITableView's standard section footer view font (SF UI Text Regular 17 vs. SF UI Text Regular 13). The default NSAttributedString text color is also black, which does not match the standard gray.
- `-[UITableView footerViewForSection:]` only works for custom footer views provided by `-tableView:viewForFooterInSection:` and returns nil otherwise. The only way is to get the standard footer view (to determine the standard font and color values) is to NOT provide a custom footer view. The view passed to `-tableView:willDisplayFooterView:forSection:` can then be cast to `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` and inspected. This seems to be undocumented behavior, and the font attributes come too late to be useful for e.g. calculating the footer view height.

#### Determining the footer view height:

- UITableView asks for the footer's height (`-tableView:heightForFooterInSection:`) before asking for the view (`-tableView:viewForFooterInSection:`). This means I need to instantiate the view in order to calculate its height early on, e.g. at `-viewDidLoad` time. But `-[UITableViewHeaderFooterView sizeToFit]` calculates the height to be 0. In fact, `textLabel`'s height isn't calculated until AFTER `-tableView:willDisplayFooterView:forSection:`, presumably since the footer view isn't added to any container view yet.
- If I use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, UITableView calculates the footer view's height based on the title (from `-tableView:titleForFooterInSection:` or equivalent value encoded in storyboard/xib). This doesn't happen until immediately before `-tableView:willDisplayFooterView:forSection:`.

#### Implementing hyperlinks:

- UITableViewHeaderFooterView provides text labels, but UILabel doesn't support tappable links, so I need to add a UITextView to the footer view. At `-tableView:willDisplayFooterView:forSection:` time, UITableViewHeaderFooterView's `textLabel` still has zero frame and nil superview, so I can't figure out how to match its frame.

## Possible solution

This is the shortest, cleanest solution I could come up with. I'm still hard-coding the font and `textContainerInset`, which is not ideal.

```
class LinkTableViewHeaderFooterView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRectZero)

    private func _setUpTextView() {
        textView.editable = false
        textView.scrollEnabled = false
        textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, -5.0, 0.0, -5.0) // hard-coded
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.addSubview(textView)
    }

    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        _setUpTextView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        _setUpTextView()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.textView.frame = self.textLabel!.frame // Match frame
    }

}

class MyViewController: UITableViewController {

    var footerAttributedText: NSAttributedString!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        :

        self.tableView.registerClass(LinkTableViewHeaderFooterView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "LinkTableViewHeaderFooterView")

        let html = "<a href=\"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum\">Lorem ipsum</a> dolor sit amet, <a href=\"http://www.example.com/\">consectetur</a> adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod <a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com\">tempor incididunt ut</a> labore et dolore magna aliqua."
        // HTML -> NSAttributedString
        let data = html.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let options: [String: AnyObject] = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding]
        self.footerAttributedText = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
}

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if section == 1 {
            return self.footerAttributedText.string // UITableView will use this value to determine footer height
        }

        return nil
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        if section == 1 {
            return tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("LinkTableViewHeaderFooterView")
        }

        return nil
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        if section == 1 {
            guard let footerView = view as? LinkTableViewHeaderFooterView else { return }

            let fontAttribute = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleFootnote) // hard-coded
            let textColorAttribute = (footerView.textLabel?.attributedText?.attribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, atIndex: 0, effectiveRange: nil))! // preserve font color
            let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: fontAttribute, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColorAttribute]

            let mutableAttributedText = self.footerAttributedText.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
            mutableAttributedText.addAttributes(attributes, range: NSMakeRange(0, mutableAttributedText.length))
            footerView.textView.attributedText = mutableAttributedText
            footerView.textView.tintColor = tableView.tintColor

            footerView.textLabel?.attributedText = mutableAttributedText // UITableView will use this value to layout the footer view
            footerView.textLabel?.hidden = true
        }
    }

}
```

If anyone has any improvements or ideas, I would love to hear them.

Comment: Pretty good solution. One issue I ran into was getting the background of the footer view to be completely transparent. Setting clear on backgroundView.backgroundColor, backgroundColor, or contentView.backgroundColor doesn't do it. Turns out you have to set backgroundView on UITableViewHeaderFooterView to an new empty UIView (iOS 9).